# Change version of iOS supported after app release?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, bundle

We're tight on time, so we're planning to release our app with iOS 6 support only first, then in a future update add support for iOS 5. (We want to support the iPad 1, which still has a decent chunk of the market, and can't use iOS 6.)

This is doable, right? There isn't some restriction about not being able to reduce the version of iOS your app requires after you release it? I think all I'd need to do to make this work is change the version of iOS my app required in Xcode, but I wanted to check to make sure.

Thanks!

Comment: No restriction man, as rmaddy said in his answer you can do it with an update later. Don't forget to check his answer as the correct one and happy coding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is fine. Change your app's Deployment Target to 5.0 (or whatever you want), test, and submit an update.